# Looking for a database or text file of english words with their different forms

Tags: nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I am working on a project and I need to get the root of a given word (stemming). As you know, the stemming algorithms that don't use a dictionary are not accurate. Also I tried the WordNet but it is not good for my project. I found phpmorphy project but it doesn't include API in Java.

At this time I am looking for a database or a text file of english words with their different forms. for example:

run running ran ...
include including included ...
...

Thank you for your help or advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could download [LanguageTool](http://languagetool.org/) (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer), which comes with a binary file `english.dict`. [The LanguageTool Wiki](http://wiki.languagetool.org/developing-a-tagger-dictionary) describes how to dump that file as a text file:

```
java -jar morfologik-tools-1.6.0-standalone.jar fsa_dump -x -d english.dict
```

For `run`, the file will contain this:

```
ran run VBD
run run NN
run run VB
run run VBN
run run VBP
running run VBG
runs run NNS
runs run VBZ
```

The first column is the inflected form, the second is the base form, and the third is the part-of-speech tag according to the (slightly extended) [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).

Comment: Since '13 that tool seems to have changed significantly. Which would the same parameters today to achieve same output? I can't find the stemming parameter. Is it still there? Also, I see that the genitive case e.g. `orthography's` is recognized as `<S> orthography[orthography/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular]'['/POS]s[s/POS,</S>]`. Is that correct?

Comment: [The wiki](http://wiki.languagetool.org/developing-a-tagger-dictionary#toc2) has a command that works for me with LanguageTool 3.9: `java -cp languagetool.jar org.languagetool.tools.DictionaryExporter -i org/languagetool/resource/en/english.dict -info org/languagetool/resource/en/english.info -o dictionary.dump`