# Ruby NLP: Get possible grammatical variations of a word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nlp

Is there a Ruby library out there that can give me the possible grammatical variations for a word?

For example, take the word "engineer". I want to get back: "engineering" as a possible variation.

Comment: Tense is a property of a verb (and a few more categories), it is not a property of a noun (at least in English). In addition, `-ing` is usually not called a tense.

Comment: I knew someone would say that. Anyway, you know what I meant!

Comment: Not a library, but just the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366071/looking-for-a-database-or-text-file-of-english-words-with-their-different-forms/18386728#18386728 - as this can be expressed as a simple text file you might not need a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want the *derivationally related forms* from [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=engineer&i=8&h=10000010000#c). There are multiple WordNet APIs that can help you achieve that (in Python, Java and Perl ... I don't know about other languages).

What you are actually searching for are *inflections* of words. English happens to be a pretty notorious natural language for systematically inferring inflections. The derivationally related forms in WordNet are not going to be exhaustive. I think you are better off looking at digital (online or offline) English dictionaries, and extracting the inflections from the gloss. The semi-structured nature of dictionary glosses will make this quite simple. For example, you can look at [the definition of 'engineer' at the Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/engineer).

You may also want to try AGID on [Kevin's Word List Page](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/). I have never used it myself (because I ended up using a dictionary as explained above), but it seems to be doing what you want.

**Finally, as far as a Ruby library is concerned**, I would recommend the [Linguistics](http://www.deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics/) project. I think what you want is in their [Conjugation](http://www.deveiate.org/code/linguistics/Linguistics/EN/Conjugation.html) module. I had stopped visiting their page a while ago because the project appeared to be dormant. But it seems those guys have picked it up again.

Comment: I ended up looking at the Porter Stemmer which is excellent since it's used in ElasticSearch but your answer lead me to the right path. Arigato!