# How to get all variants of word part of speech?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

POS taggers AFAIK show only one variant of possible part of speech. Is there tool or library (preferrably for Python) which gives all variants?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366071/looking-for-a-database-or-text-file-of-english-words-with-their-different-forms/18386728#18386728

Comment: Wnen executing command "java -cp languagetool-standalone.jar org.languagetool.dev.DictionaryExporter org/languagetool/resource/en/english.dict >dictionary.dump" as described here: http://wiki.languagetool.org/developing-a-tagger-dictionary I receive following error: "Could not find or load main class org.languagetool.dev.DictionaryExporter"

Comment: The file is now called ```languagetool.jar``` instead of ```languagetool-standalone.jar```.

Comment: That linked answer doesn't look like it (necessarily) addresses the use case which was: show all possible parts of speech. Perhaps you could clarify...

Comment: Daniel's answer addresses the problem by linking to a program which generates a file which contains all parts of speech of a given word. That can be used to solve OP's question